# Magento prioritise discounts by discount amount

Tags: magento

I currently have all my discounts set with a priority of '0'.  Some discounts share the same products.

In this case I need magento to apply the rule which gives the greatest discount.  At the moment magento does not seem to do this, it just looks at which discount has the highest priority and applies that one.  Is there an extension or a code change I can make to get the discounts to behave like I want them to, where the largest discount always takes priority.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I would be very glad to know! Thanks